# Cassandra terminates connection in the middle?

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

I'm using Cassandra driver for java from datastax. I know that I have 20 millions of rows in one table. When I using

```
Select * from table
```

The process stops after around 800000 rows have been fetched.

In my Java code

```
futureResults = session.executeAsync(statement);
ResultSet results = futureResults.getUninterruptibly();
for (Row row : results) {

}
```

Maybe I did something wrong ?

Comment: Did you check logs on cassandra.log and system.log during this? It can give you potential insight. Another problem can be network issue between client and cassandra nodes.

Comment: The program was terminated correctly, it meant there was no more row in the ResultSet to continue. I think you may be correct about the network issue, I will try to increase the connection retry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing there is a fairly common anti-pattern with Cassandra. Since each partition of data lives in different parts of your cluster, that query will create a massive scatter/gather, centered around one coordinator. Eventually things start timing out and the coordinator will throw an error. A quick look in the logs should find it.

Almost always, a select query should include a partition key for locality. If that's not possible, switching to something batch that will efficiently scan each node is best. The Spark connector for Cassandra is perfect for an access pattern like this.

Comment: So it means that my table's data may be spreaded on all around the nodes in the cluster.  I try to find how can i get all partition keys of my table, but i cant find an answer that i can understand. Do you know how can i archive that with nodetool or cqls ? Thank you

Comment: You are looking for something like sqldump that will export an entire table?

Comment: Im looking for a way to extract the partition keys of my table so i can use it in my select statement as you suggested.

Comment: This sounds like you need a index table as a part of your data model. I talk about those here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=px6U2n74q3g

Comment: This is very useful.  Thank you very much.